# Donut caching _Layout with mvcdonutcaching ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, donut-caching

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have a login submenu in the navigation menu of my shared `_Layout.cshtml` file, displaying user info if the user is logged in, or signup/login options if not. The login submenu is a partial view in my shared folder named `_LoginPartial`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //display <ul> with user profile settings, omitted for brevity
}
else
{
    //display <ul> to signup/login, omitted for brevity    
}
```

While I heavily cache several actions of various controllers, I want to implement donut caching on `_Layout` so that `_LoginPartial` does not get cached, for obvious reasons. I'm using the [mvcdonutcaching](https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching) library to accomplish this (suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23410549/1199044)) which provides some overloads of `@Html.Action` that have an additional `bool excludeFromParentCache` property.

As such, I created a `LayoutController` with a `UserAuth` action which returns `_LoginPartial`:

```
public class LayoutController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserAuth()
    {
        return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
    }
}
```

..And in my `_Layout` file, where I want `_LoginPartial` to appear, I call the mvcdonutcaching `Html.Action` overload as such:

```
@Html.Action("UserAuth", "Layout", true)
```

To test this, I have set an `OutputCache` with a long duration on the `Index` action of my `FAQController`, but if I follow these steps:

- login
- navigate to /faq
- logout
- navigate to /faq

/faq still shows me as logged in.

What am I missing here? This is mvcdonutcaching's output in the actual HTML:

```
<!--Donut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
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/manage" class="dropdown" title="Manage your account"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Account</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" title="Log out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i> Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
<!--EndDonut-->
```

**Update**: I have also tried moving the menu in `_LoginPartial` to a partial view residing in the views of `LayoutController` instead - the problem persists.

Comment: Can you also add your parent controller action?

Comment: Hey @DaveWalker, as this never got any attention I unfortunately abandoned this approach quite some time ago. If you have a working example I would be more than happy to try it and check it out.

Comment: I havent done it in ages so need to jog my memory. I wonder if it's because it's in the layout.

Comment: Could be. I want to say that I'd tried this scenario as well but it's been a while so I could be completely off :)

Comment: Can you try to move Request.IsAuthenticated to child action and return boolean model with view ? And check model on view.

Comment: Hey @MaDeRkAn. See my reply above - I have unfortunately abandoned this approach but if you believe you know why this happened I would gladly test a working solution (you can submit it as an answer). Also, what's a boolean model? Do you mean returning `View(Request.IsAuthenticated)` in the child action?

Comment: @trashr0x I have done what you did. I have created faq and ayout controller with child action which calls by layout. I have followed for your steps it has worked for me. I have used 1.3.0 for MvcDonutCaching Library.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same thing but solved it after noticing that I had inadvertently used `[OutputCache]` instead of `[DonutOutputCache]`!

User error. Works in `_Layout` beautifully. Please double-check that you are using the proper `[DonutOutputCache]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Move your action to `Account` or `Member` Controller avoid using `LayoutController`.

You should check the Official Demo:  https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching/tree/master/DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching.Demo

Especially `AccountController` and views...

Regards...

Comment: Why avoid using a LayoutController?